# Class with no fields have constructor . is it possible ?

Tags: oop, constructor, field

We know that Constructors initialize the data fields of object . now if we don't have any fields in our class , There is nothing to be initialized by constructors.

What do constructors do in In such a class?

Comment: What is the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is the most obvious purpose of a constructor to initialize the data fields, it is by no means the only one.

The main purpose of the constructor is to create an object of the class. Without having an object, it is not possible to call any non-static methods of the class. You might say that non-static methods make no sense if the class has no data fields, but this is not true because derived classes might have data fields.

You should generally consider that the class could be part of a class hierarchy. (In Java, this is always the case because every class is derived from `Object`.) A constructor typically calls constructors of the base class.

Constructors can also have side effects. An example would be a message written to a log file. The created object could also be registered in some list when the constructor is called.